# Unique Calendar Entry identifier

Tags: swift, macos, icalendar, ekevent

I am receiving events from the calendar. I am saving them in a separate database and I want to update them if they change. 
I want to add a unique identifier for each calendar entry. The Problem are reoccuring events. The do not seem to have a unique identifier. This is how i tried to receive it.
Is there a unique identifier for a calendar entry or a changelog for entries?

```
print(event.calendarItemIdentifier)
let eventK = event as! EKEvent
print("event \(getEventName(eventK)) identifie \(event.calendarItemIdentifier) external \(event.calendarItemExternalIdentifier)")
print(event as! EKCalendarItem );
print(eventK)
```

Answer (score -1):

not being familiar with `swift`, i'm not sure the format about the actual data you are getting.

However since you are mentionning icalendar, the standard for this is `RFC5545` which states in section [§3.8.4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.4)

> 3.8.4.4.  Recurrence ID
>
> Property Name:  RECURRENCE-ID

> Purpose:  This property is used in conjunction with the "UID" and
> "SEQUENCE" properties to identify a specific instance of a
> recurring "VEVENT", "VTODO", or "VJOURNAL" calendar component.
> The property value is the original value of the "DTSTART" property
> of the recurrence instance.

So in other words, to get a unique identifier for an event, you need to look for the `UID` property.
For a recurring event, you need to look for the `RECURENCE-ID`

Comment: This would be fine but how to a retrieve the reocurrence-id. I can get the reocurrence rule but i find no id `Optional([EKRecurrenceRule <0xaff00> RRULE FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR])
`